# Why does typeof(Object[,][]).Name equal "Object[][,]"?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, multidimensional-array

Evaluating `typeof(Object[,][]).Name` gives `Object[][,]`

Similarly, `typeof(Object[][,]).Name` gives `Object[,][]`

Seems like the comma is moving for no reason.

What gives?

Comment: I find the rule of changing position of comma but I don't know why it is acting like that. Comma reflecting to the center of array. For example; `[,][][][][]` gives you `[][][][][,]`, `[][,][][][]` gives you `[][][][,][]`, `[][][,][][]` gives you `[][][,][][]` as a result.

Comment: @SonerGönül: Try `[][,][,,][,,,][,,,,]` -- now is it clear what is going on?

Comment: @EricLippert Yep, thanks. Also `FullName` property gives the same results. Maybe that's why we called it **reflection**

Comment: @SonerGönül: Hilarious!

Comment: I had a situation where I needed to convert a jagged array of rectangular arrays into a jagged array of jagged arrays. `T[][][,]` to `T[][][][]` and never run into a problem. So `C#` designers did what would be natural for a programmer in this case. Of course had I looked a the reflected type I would been thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mixing ragged and rectangular arrays is a recipe for insanity. Your intuition about what a given type notation means is almost always wrong, or, at least, mine is.

Read my article on the subject and see if that helps you understand what is going on here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays.aspx

Basically: C# and reflection notate mixed ragged/rectangular arrays in two different ways, each for their own reasons.

Comment: +1, Best quote from the link _"you do not actually make an element type into an array of that type by appending an array specifier."_

Comment: @ja72: Correct, in C# that is the case. But in Reflection, which does not follow the rules of C#, it just blithely sticks the array modifier onto the end of the type name, not into the middle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eric.  Don't worry - I'm not actually using any types like this in my code.  I'm writing a tool that creates a friendly list of public APIs using reflection, and this test case rang an alarm bell.

Comment: Ever since my dalliances with game dev, I exclusively use flat 1d arrays with indexers akin to `indexOf(x, y) => y * arrayWidth + x;` Less confusing **and** usually much faster!

Comment: This was mind blowing. While I agree with the notion that ending up in this situation is an sign of bad code, I think that C#'s interpretation of that expression is very counter intuitive. I'd feel better if I knew what my code *means* even if I have to type the declaration and the initialization differently, than writing them uniformly but being blissfully unaware of what exactly they create. To be honest, it seems to me like this is a bad language design decision. (On the other hand, of course, it is the only bad design decision I've seen in C#.)

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: Well then, when you design your own programming language you will know to not make that mistake!

Comment: @EricLippert I am, actually. =) But I hope the previous comment didn't offend you, because C# is by far my favorite language and I'm a huge fan of your work, so I'd hate it if I came across otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving aside the purpose for which you might want to declare such exotic array, it looks like the way the reflection produces the name of an array is recursive: first, it produces the name of array's element type, and then appends square brackets with the appropriate number of commas.

`Object[,][]` is a 2D array of 1D arrays; the element type of the 2D array is `Object[]`, so the overall result is `"Object[]"+"[,]"`.

Here is another illustration of the way the algorithm works:

```
typeof(Object[][,][,,][,,,][,,,,]).Name
```

is

```
Object[,,,,][,,,][,,][,][]
```

I don't see a reason behind it other than the efficiency of implementation: as long as it is consistent, it does not matter if the syntax matches C# or not. After all, C# is not the only language in the .NET universe.

Comment: Correct; the oddity here is that C# says that `object[,][]` is a two-d array of `object[]`, when it naively looks like it ought to be a one-d array of `object[,]`.